# Long Folder Names with EmulationStation and DosBox

Tags: emulation, retropie

I cannot launch exe files from EmulationStation if the folder name is too long, contains spaces, or other characters.

For example:
I have a folder `~/RetroPie/roms/pc/My Game (1989) [Action]` that contains an `.exe` file

When I change the folder to `~/RetroPie/roms/pc/mygame`, the game launches just fine from EmulationStation, otherwise it won't run, it just returns to ES

Any ideas on how to get these to work? I have quite a few abandonware games with folders like this, so the only options I can think of are renaming all of them, or creating symbolic links with more DOS-friendly names (less than 8 characters long, no special characters, etc)

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the file name/path in quotes?

Comment: Yea. Didn't seem to help, even when I used the abbreviated form e.g. MYGAME~1, I just get an invalid path. But they work great if I rename them beforehand.

Comment: I was actually wondering if LFN folders worked as mount points, and where the script would be that initializes the dos emulator before running it from emulation station, perhaps I could turn the parameter into the C: mount point, then run the exe from C:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented [here](https://superuser.com/questions/511544/dosbox-8-3-filenames-disagree-with-windows-7) and in [this forum thread](http://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=40610) the latest [DOSBox 0.74](http://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1) still lacks long filename support so you should [rename](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-725941.html) the files to 8.3 file names or call the filename ######~1 etc.

In the latest [thread](http://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=40610) however they are working on supporting long file names. You can get the latest code and some binaries on [www.dosbox.com/wiki/SVN_Builds](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/SVN_Builds#Enhanced_SVN_builds). For Linux you could try the SVN builds of [Taewoong's page](http://ykhwong.x-y.net/), otherwise try other pages of [dosbox](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/SVN_Builds#Enhanced_SVN_builds).

Comment: I'll have to follow this. Thanks for the heads up!